# How can I remove the active class from a li?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my navbar. I just need to remove the active class from a `li` to put this class to the second `li` while scrolling, here is the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 650) {
    $('#about').addClass("active");
  } else {
    $('#home').removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

Comment: You realize that you are attempting to remove the class from `#home`, when it had been added to `#about`, right?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear?

Comment: take a look to 
[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: The removeClass call is correct so check your selector if you have the correct element. (e.g. Is your element with id "home" the correct element you want to remove the class"active" from?)

Comment: yea i want to remove the class from #home to add it to #about

Comment: Where are you setting the `active` class on `#home`. Please show us all the relevant code.

Comment: the class already in #home.i just want when i scroll top remove it from it to add it to #about

Comment: Add `$('#home').removeClass("active");` inside the `if` block and see if that's what you want.

Comment: @AhmedMohsen if you're looking for change 'active' class between two <li> on specific height .. for sure siam answer will work with you .. but for me it sounds like you're trying to create a one page website and trying to active a button while scrolling to its active area  .. if that is the case , I made this for you hope it helps https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/rw0v7q38/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `removeClass()` for `#home` id while `addClass()` for `#about` element and vice versa . So, the following code will work :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 650) {
        $('#about').addClass("active");
        $('#home').removeClass("active");
    } else {
        $('#about').removeClass("active");
        $('#home').addClass("active");
    }
});
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 650) {
    $('#about').addClass("active");
    $('#home').removeClass("active");
  } else {
   $('#about').removeClass("active");
    $('#home').addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.fixed{
  position : fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
.long{
  height : 5000px;
}
.active{
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed">
  <div id="home" class="active">Home</div>
  <div id="about">About</div>
</div>
<div class="long"></div>
```

Comment: toggleClass('active')

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef oh, my bad. thanks for correcting :)

Comment: this is what your code doing https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/rw0v7q38/ ... and this is the right one .. https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/rw0v7q38/1/ .. you can update your answer with this .. its yours :) good luck

Comment: TYSM man. much appreciated :-) Tho I knew that issue.. just got busy w/ something else.. couldn't update it properly :/

Comment: You're totally welcome bro :-) .. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question which I think is not detailed enough and let take a look at your code"

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 650) {

        $('#about').addClass("active"); 
        //This is when you add class active, but you have to remove class active
        //from #about as well

    } else {

        $('#home').removeClass("active");
        //Same thing here, you have to remove class active from #about
    }

});
```

if you dont remove active class from the other element, after you scroll up and down you end it up having class active in both elements. Hope I read your question right and answer your question.